# Handle drop down menu in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, locate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8w7q.png)[I want to locate that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn8ky.png)

I want to locate menu bar that is drop down.

Comment: You need to provide some html for the element because only after that it can be identified the right way to click.

Comment: uploaded html for the section.kindly check

Comment: Image is not clear enough, can you please add again (little bigger). The site, is it internal or open to public (so can have a look)...